# Debugging Asp net core oauth signin using Wordpress and logging out properly

Tags: c#, wordpress, asp.net-core, oauth

I need to make my app signon via Wordpress. (ASP NET CORE 3.1). I have tried a couple of things and settled on an Oauth2 approach. I am presently evaluating the WP OAuth server.
I have watched a series of execellent tutorial videos from Raw Coding here:[ASP NET Core3 Authentication](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/) up to dealing with OAuth servers and I think I get it, but I admit that coming from ASP.NET to Core as well as learning the intricacies of Oauth and the sample package has been quite a learning curve.

I have succeeded so far, by using [WP-Oauth server](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/) on the Wordpress installation and a simple setup on the Asp app. The WP-Oauth only provides the login and the token however, so I need to go and get the users details via the REST api after logging in. I did this using the WordpressPCL which is geared to using JSON Webtokens.
I need to obtain more specialised information from the user once they sign in so I am using the individual user accounts as well.

My question relates to debugging and that I need to 'log out' properly in order to fully re-invoke the login process but I want to detail some of the issues I have experienced here so as to help others that might need to do this. I am not an expert in this area, I have previously used the Identity code in asp.net pretty much as a 'black box', and not finding anything to help in this cherished site, I have just struggled through and I figure this might help someone else.

I have succeeded in doing this by setting up the startup as follows:

```
        services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddOAuth("WordPress", options =>
         {
             options.ClientId = Configuration["WordPress:ClientId"];
             options.ClientSecret = Configuration["WordPress:ClientSecret"];
             options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/wordpress-oauth");
             options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["WordPress:AuthorizationEndpoint"];  //WPserverURL + "/oauth/authorize";
             options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["WordPress:TokenEndPoint"]; // WPserverURL + "/oauth/token";
             options.SaveTokens = true;
             options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
             options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");

             options.Events = new OAuthEvents()
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.AccessToken;

                    var wpclient = new WordPressClient("https://dev.butcherhouse.co.uk/wp-json/");
                    wpclient.AuthMethod = AuthMethod.JWT;
                    wpclient.SetJWToken(context.AccessToken);
                    //var user = await wpclient.Users.GetCurrentUser();
                    //var userJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

                    var userdetails = await wpclient.CustomRequest.Get<UserDetailDTO>("wp/v2/users/me?context=edit", false, true);

                    Claim UserId = new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userdetails.id.ToString());
                    Claim UserEmail = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userdetails.email);
                    Claim FirstName = new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userdetails.first_name);
                    Claim LastName = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, userdetails.last_name);
                    List<Claim> Roles = new List<Claim>();
                    foreach(string role in userdetails.roles)
                    {
                        Roles.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                    }

                    context.Identity.AddClaim(UserId);
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(UserEmail);
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(FirstName);
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(LastName);
                    context.Principal.AddIdentity(context.Identity);
                }
             };
        });
```

The UserDetailDTO looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// The details from the WP GET Users/me?contex=edit call
/// </summary>
    public class UserDetailDTO
{
    // Start with just the things we need
    public int? id;
    public string first_name;
    public string last_name;
    public string email;
    public List<string> roles;
}
```

I modified the ExternalLogin.cshtml by:
Adding first and last names to the InputModel:

```
    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Extracting the Names from the claims:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor : true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", info.Principal.Identity.Name, info.LoginProvider);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            LoginProvider = info.LoginProvider;
            if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email))
            {
                Input = new InputModel
                {
                    Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                };
                if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName))
                {
                    Input.FirstName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
                }
                if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname))
                {
                    Input.LastName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Surname);
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

... and the OnPostConfirmationAsync as follows:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information during confirmation.";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new TTPlannerServerUser
            {
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email,
                FirstName = Input.FirstName,
                LastName = Input.LastName
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                    // Adding the Role claims here   ****Unable to test this****
                    if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role))
                    {
                        IEnumerable<Claim> roleclaims = info.Principal.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role);
                        await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, roleclaims);
                    }

                    // If account confirmation is required, we need to show the link if we don't have a real email sender
                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("./RegisterConfirmation", new { Email = Input.Email });
                    }

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        LoginProvider = info.LoginProvider;
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return Page();
    }
```

This works as far as executing the login with the wordpress server, getting the names, email id etc.
I am having difficulty though in testing the claims part of it (roles) because once the user has signed in, the tokens seem to hang around or the server re-issues them without logging in again.
But since I added the claims element later, I need to ensure that the user is properly 'logged out'.
I have added code to delete cookies in the logout code as follows:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");

        //Clear the ASP cookies
        foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
        }

        if (returnUrl != null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
```

What do I need to do to get to a 'clean slate' between debug runs? Also in any event, it doesnt seem a great situation if I can't log a user out fully anyway...
Thanks in advance,
Brett

Comment: You can refer to the three session layers that Auth0 usually needs to consider when implementing the logout function: https://auth0.com/docs/logout

Comment: Thank you @Yongqing, this information looks useful, but you do realise that I'm not using Auth0 don't you? I am unsure how far to take it as there is quite a lot of good info in there relating to asp net core but it is an openid solution. I realise it is similar to Oauth, but how similar is it?